# How to apply style only for first level menu

Tags: html, css

Here i have the menu structure, what am i trying to do is that, when i click the parent level item or any sub menu item the class `active` is going to get added to the menu which is clicked.

i want to change the color of only the parent menu item but not the sub menu item, how can i do that. right now what is happening is that i have applied css, but its getting applied to parent menu as well as the child menu items.

```css
.center-in-menu {
  &:not(div.we-mega-menu-submenu) {
    .we-mega-menu-li.active {
      a {
        color: blue !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-tabs center-in-menu">
<li class="we-mega-menu-li dropdown-menu">
<a href="#">Menu 1</a>
<div class="we-mega-menu-submenu">
  <ul class="nav-tabs">
    <li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
    <li class="we-mega-menu-li dropdown-menu"><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
    <div class="we-mega-menu-submenu">
      <ul class="nav-tabs">
        <li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
        <li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
        <li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
        <li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
        <li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">submenu3</a></li>
    <li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">submenu4</a></li>
    <li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">submenu5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
<li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
<li class="we-mega-menu-li dropdown-menu">
  <a href="3">Menu 4</a>
  <div class="we-mega-menu-submenu">
    <ul class="nav-tabs">
      <li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li class="we-mega-menu-li active dropdown-menu"><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
      <div class="we-mega-menu-submenu">
        <ul class="nav-tabs">
          <li class="we-mega-menu-li active"><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
          <li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
          <li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">submenu3</a></li>
          <li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">submenu4</a></li>
          <li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">submenu5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">submenu3</a></li>
      <li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">submenu4</a></li>
      <li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">submenu5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="we-mega-menu-li"><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Example here
https://codepen.io/Chandanay/pen/YzKJNEE

Comment: Put a working example.

Comment: <li class="we-mega-menu-li dropdown-menu">
    <a href="#">Menu 1</a>  is that your parent menu

Comment: I have added the link to example @DAMMAK

Comment: Updated with example @Alex

Comment: The _only_ place where you have `a` elements here are your top-level menu items - so it is unclear how the CSS you have shown _could_ even have an effect on more than one level here.

Comment: And your selector does not make much sense either, `.center-in-menu {
  &:not(div.we-mega-menu-submenu)` will actually result in `.center-in-menu:not(div.we-mega-menu-submenu)` - your `.center-in-menu` _is_ not a div element to begin with, so demanding that it not be one is kinda superfluous …

Comment: My bad, i forgot to add a in li. updated now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `>` to apply styles only to elements inside the given selector without going deeper any further.

Here's an example:

```
div.wrapper > a {  /* only applied to direct children */
    font-weight: bold;
}

div.inner a {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

---

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a>1st Level (Bold)</a>
    <div class="inner">
        <a>2nd Level (Italic)</a>
    </div>
    <div class="noclass">
        <a>2nd Level (No style)</a>
    </div>
</div>
```